# Trying to alert value of same selector in two iterations, getting correct value in 1st iteration and incorrect one in second. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**[JSFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/ug9gq5ha/2/)**

In the following SSCCE,there are two `.inner-table` elements. I have used JQuery `each()` to iterate through them. Then inside each `.inner-table`, I iterate through each `<tr>` to find out and alert the value of the `<input>.color-name` element, by using `val()` function.

The problem is that in the first iteration, the alert showing value of `<input>.color-name` shows correct value I entered into the text field, but in the second iteration (i.e. *for the second `inner-table`*), the alert seems to show an empty string no matter what I write into the text field.

The question is why? What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).on("click", "#button", function(event) {
  //event.preventDefault();
  alert('Button clicked.'); //check
  var colorName;
  var dataJSON = {};

  $(".inner-table").each(function() {
    var dataUnit = [];
    dataJSON.dataUnit = dataUnit;
    var iterationCount = 1;
    
    $(this).find("tbody tr").each(function() {
      alert("Iteration " + iterationCount); //check
      //alert($(this).html());//check
      if ($(this).find("td .color-name").length) {
        colorName = $(this).find("td .color-name").val();
        alert(colorName); //check
      }
      iterationCount++;
    });

    var color = {
      "colorName": colorName
    };

    dataJSON.dataUnit.push(color);
  });

  console.log("dataJSON > " + JSON.stringify(dataJSON)); //check
});
```

```css
.outer-table tr {
  margin: 30px;
}
.inner-table {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">
  Click
</button>
<table class="outer-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table class="inner-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p class="input-label">Name of Color</p>
                <input class="input-field color-name" type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table class="inner-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <p class="input-label">Name of Color</p>
                <input class="input-field colorName" type="text" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a wrong class name in the second td. you are using "colorName" it should be "color-name"

Answer (score 1):

You should read more on the `each` API here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/. You should change your callback function to accept parameters including the iteration variable, rather than declaring your own. I think that is start of your solution. In the jsfiddle, the iterator variable never seems to advance in the alerts popped up.